# ionic 2 how to customize ion-range?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, range, ionic2

in ionic 2, I want to customize the **ion-range** to be something like the following 
pic, or I should say : is there way to customize **ion-range** ?:
[image]

here is my code

```html
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-range min="500" max="1500" step="500" snaps="true" color="secondary"></ion-range>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
```

and here is my range

[image]

Comment: What did you attemp already? Please post some code or a problem you are facing

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to add image on thumb ?

Answer (score 5):

I did find out how to customize **"ion-range"**, and here is what I built (I know it look not exact):

[image]

here are my steps:-
1- add these line of codes shown on picture to your src\theme\variables.scss 
[image]

Note: there is many variables you can use to customize your ion-range in the folowing link [ionic2 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/range/Range/#sass-variables)

2- here is my component code:

```html
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-33 text-left>
        Sedan
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33 text-center>
        SUV
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33 text-right>
        LUX
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-range (ionChange)="selectCar()" min="500" max="1500" step="500" snaps="true" [(ngModel)]="value">
    </ion-range>

  </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-footer>
```